# Simple Port Scanner in Python

Tags: python

I am learning to program in python3. I decided to make a port scanner but am facing an issue.

I have imported socket module and I am using a queue for threading the process but I wanted to implement it without threading.

The issue I am facing is that I call the functions but no results are showing on the screen.

```
import socket

from queue import Queue

target = "172.217.166.206"

queue = Queue()

open_port = []

def portscan(port):

    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((target, port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

def get_ports(mode):

    if mode == 1:
        for port in range(1,1024):
            queue.put(port)
    elif mode == 1:
        for port in range(1,49512):
            queue.put(port)
    elif mode == 1:
        ports = [20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 53, 80, 110, 443]
        for port in ports:
            queue.put(port)
    elif mode == 4:
        ports = input("Enter your ports (seperate by blank):")
        ports = ports.split()
        ports = list(map(int, ports))
        for port in ports:
            queue.put(port)

def worker():

    while not queue.empty():
        port = queue.get()
        result = portscan(port)
        if result:
            print("Port {} is open".format(port))
        else:
            print("Port {} is closed".format(port))


mode = input(" Press 1 for reserved ports \n Press 2 for all ports \n Press 3 for Critical ports \n Press 4 for manual ports \n")

get_ports(mode)

worker()
```

Comment: Your two `elif mode == 1:` blocks are never going to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` function in Python 3 does return `str` - if you type `1` it would be `'1'` and you inside `get_ports` compares it with `1` (integer), because in python `'1'==1` and other `str` vs `int` equal checks are `False` your `get_port` do nothing. You have to change what `input` return to integer, namely do:

```
mode = int(input(" Press 1 for reserved ports \n Press 2 for all ports \n Press 3 for Critical ports \n Press 4 for manual ports \n"))
```

in place of

```
mode = input(" Press 1 for reserved ports \n Press 2 for all ports \n Press 3 for Critical ports \n Press 4 for manual ports \n")
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. I forgot to typecast the input.